# How can energy be partitioned equally when energy is relative?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, potential-energy

According to the [Equipartition theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) in a system at equilibrium the energy should be on average be divided equally between the available degrees of freedom. The most common examples are the three linear velocities, rotations, and harmonic vibrations. These all have nice square relationships where the state of zero energy is neatly defined. So it is easy to set $E_{translational_x}=E_{rotational_y}=\frac12k_bT$ for example and have that statement be meaningful. However, if there is for example $E_{gravity}$ as given in the [Sedimentation of particles example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Sedimentation_of_particles), then the energy depends on your choice of origin. In this case setting $E_{gravity}=k_bT$ would mean different things depending on your origin.

I would like to know how to use the Equipartition Theorem to get origin independent results using an origin dependent potential energy.

For example suppose for a system:

$$ H = m\,g\,\alpha $$

Where alpha is a degree of freedom corresponding to a linear position. Then it follows that

$$\left\langle \alpha \frac{\partial H}{\partial\alpha} \right\rangle = k_b\,T $$
$$\langle m\,g\,\alpha \rangle = k_b\,T $$
$$\langle\alpha \rangle = \frac{k_b\,T}{m\,g} $$

Now if we re-define our degree of freedom by a coordinate transform $\beta = \alpha + \beta_0$ then:

$$ H = m\,g\,(\beta -\beta_0) $$
$$\left\langle \beta \frac{\partial H}{\partial\beta} \right\rangle = k_b\,T $$
$$\langle m\,g\,\beta \rangle = k_b\,T $$
$$\langle\beta \rangle = \frac{k_b\,T}{m\,g} $$
$$\langle\alpha+\beta_0 \rangle = \frac{k_b\,T}{m\,g} $$

Which contradicts our previous result.

How can a coordinate transformation produce consistent results?

If it ties in nicely, answers could also note how a change in relative velocity of the origin could work, but I'm not sure that is feasible as bulk velocity is not considered in temperature measurements.

Comment: The equipartiton theorem is false for non-quadratic contributions to the energy.

Comment: @RobinEkman Could you site a source? I'm pretty sure it's been used in systems with gravity, nuclear spins, and other non quadratic energy contributions, as sited in the second link.

Comment: I was thinking of the theorem that $U = \frac 1 2 k_B T$. This is false except for quadratic degrees of freedom. However, the general equipartition theorem holds more generally. In the case of another power law, the equipartitioned quantity is some other constant times the energy. But if the energy is a a more general function, like a sum of powers, the relation between the equipartitioned quantity and the energy will be more complicated, and will depend on the form of the potential. Compare with the exposition here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Anharmonic_oscillators

Comment: Note that since the expression for the equipartitioned quantity involves a derivative on the Hamiltonian, adding a constant to the potential has no influence.